# Blueprint CSS form element size discrepancy

Tags: blueprint-css

I love Blueprint CSS framework.

But there's something I don't understand about its default form element size.

As you can see at http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/forms.html , [select] field is considerably smaller than [text] field. I think it's intentional. Do you think it's ok and good? If not, how do you cope with it?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I put a wrapper around the form elements and set the column size on that, then I set the form elements to be width of 98% of their parent, that gets them just about right with a bit of padding , much more visibly appealing.